# Bash, get values from json file, all in one line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Is possible get data for one specific product, closed in `{ }`, from json, by `EAN`, all data are in one line?

**Example**

Input.

```
...

{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}},{ "article" ...

...
```

Expected output (command selected by `code` `01333457004`), via `sed` or `awk`?

```
{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a minimal testable example of input (i.e. a valid JSON sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just split the file into one entry per line first. That makes parsing it much simpler. So, find all cases of `},{` and add a newline breaking them:

```
$ sed 's/},{/},\n{/g' file
{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}},
{ "article" ...
```

Now, you can just search for your code. But use the `-w` flag for `grep` which makes it look for "words" to avoid finding the code as a substring. So if you have one line with code `01333457004` and another line with code `013334570041`, searching for `01333457004` won't find `013334570041`.

Putting all this together gives:

```
$ sed 's/},{/},\n{/g' file | grep 01333457004
{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}},
```

---

If you really want to do it in a single operation, you can try using grep with `-P` for PCRE regular expressions which support [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -oP '{ "article":.*?\b01333457004\b.*?}(?=,{)' file
{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}}
```

This will look for `{ "article":`, then the shortest stretch of 0 or more characters (`.*?`) until the string `01333457004`, but only if that appears surrounded by non-word characters, so only if it is a word; that's what the `\b` mean, then the shortest stretch of 0 or more characters again that end with a `}` followed by `,}`.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jq.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key)

Probably in your case it should be something like:

```
cat test.json | jq '.[] | select(.article.code | contains("01333457004"))'
```

Comment: Can you get this to work? I get an error: `null (null) and string ("01333457004") cannot have their containment checked`. Also another error due to the file's syntax, but that one seems to be about `jq`. Also, you don't need the `cat`, you can just do `jq 'foo' test.json`.

Comment: I can get this error if there is an article without code. Try:
`jq '.[] | select(.article.code | . and  contains("01333457004"))' test.json`
or
`jq '.[] | select(.article.code | contains("01333457004"))?' test.json`

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP's input isn't valid JSON. `jq` is absolutely the way to go, but only if we can have valid JSON as input.

Comment: JSON is mentioned In the question, so I assumed is an valid JSON.